# Operation on Large Numbers In php

Tags: php, gmp

I need to solve a problem, this is what I have tried.

```
$sum = 0;
for($i=1; $i<=1000; $i++){     
  $sum += gmp_strval(gmp_pow($i, $i) );
}
echo $sum;
```

result produce as **INF**, is this possible to get result other than **Infinity**

Comment: If you consistently use gmp (e.g. for your addition to $sum), then yes it is

Comment: Thanks it solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `$sum` need to be a **gmp number**, or else it will be **INF** when you overflow php max Integer size

```
<?php

$sum = 0;
for($i=1; $i<=1000; $i++){     
  $sum = gmp_add($sum, gmp_pow($i, $i));
}
echo gmp_strval($sum);
```